# scraping: download files from url

Tags: python, r, curl, selenium, web-scraping

I want to automatically download files from this [page](http://oilandgas.ky.gov/Pages/ProductionReports.aspx).

I tried many methods like:

```
download.file
read.table
GET
```

But without success. I am not asking for code , but I am asking for any hint/idea to deal with such situation.

Comment: With Python, a common approach is to use [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/)

Comment: Why doesn't download.file work? Works for me.

Comment: @Spacedman can you show me this please? Maybe I miss something?

Comment: Its not our job to show you what we did that worked. Its your job to show US what YOU tried and failed. You've not done this. Please edit your question with more details.

Comment: @Spacedman you are right(generally I show what I have tried, maybe you already know that). I don't have a pc (right now) and I will edit my question once I get that.

Comment: I suspect its because the links on that page open the data in a Sharepoint spreadsheet web page, but maybe you know that, and maybe you've already tried getting the data via the URL in the File menu on that page...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Python version that use [`BeautifulSoup`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/).

```
try:
    # Python 3.x
    from urllib.request import urlopen, urlretrieve, quote
    from urllib.parse import urljoin
except ImportError:
    # Python 2.x
    from urllib import urlopen, urlretrieve, quote
    from urlparse import urljoin

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'http://oilandgas.ky.gov/Pages/ProductionReports.aspx'
u = urlopen(url)
try:
    html = u.read().decode('utf-8')
finally:
    u.close()

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
for link in soup.select('div[webpartid] a'):
    href = link.get('href')
    if href.startswith('javascript:'):
        continue
    filename = href.rsplit('/', 1)[-1]
    href = urljoin(url, quote(href))
    try:
        urlretrieve(href, filename)
    except:
        print('failed to download')
```

Comment: Thanks for this solution. `BeautifulSoup` is really Beautiful.

Answer (score 5):

This works for me:

```
getIt = function(what,when){ 
     url=paste0("http://oilandgas.ky.gov/Production%20Reports%20Library/",
                 when,"%20-%20",what,
                "%20Production.xls")
     destfile=paste0("/tmp/",what,when,".xls")
     download.file(url,destfile)
}
```

for example:

```
> getIt("gas",2006)
trying URL 'http://oilandgas.ky.gov/Production%20Reports%20Library/2006%20-%20gas%20Production.xls'
Content type 'application/vnd.ms-excel' length 3490304 bytes (3.3 Mb)
opened URL
==================================================
downloaded 3.3 Mb
```

EXCEPT for the first one:

```
> getIt("oil",2010)
trying URL 'http://oilandgas.ky.gov/Production%20Reports%20Library/2010%20-%20oil%20Production.xls'
Error in download.file(url, destfile) : 
  cannot open URL 'http://oilandgas.ky.gov/Production%20Reports%20Library/2010%20-%20oil%20Production.xls'
In addition: Warning message:
In download.file(url, destfile) :
  cannot open: HTTP status was '404 NOT FOUND'
```

although I can get 2010's gas data:

```
> getIt("gas",2010)
trying URL 'http://oilandgas.ky.gov/Production%20Reports%20Library/2010%20-%20gas%20Production.xls'
Content type 'application/vnd.ms-excel' length 4177408 bytes (4.0 Mb)
opened URL
==================================================
downloaded 4.0 Mb
```

So it looks like they changed the system for that one link. You can get that data by following the link and then looking for the download link in the cruddy Sharepoint HTML.

And this is why we hate Sharepoint, kiddies.

Comment: +1 I hate it too sharepoint but it is everywhere :) You can see my attempt, it works even with thee first file. An sorry again to not show my attempt before (technical reasons).

Comment: Argh they changed to using **xlsx** instead of **xls** for the first one.